suricata no decleration found
I am having problems with my docker-compose.yaml file.
I already have bookstack running with a swag container for https security for the bookstack site.
but when I want to update the docker-compose.yaml file and add the sericuta volumes etc. i get an error even when i do docker-compose down and also with docker-compose down -v
greatguide@ubuntu:~$ docker-compose down
ERROR: Named volume "suricata_rules:/var/lib/suricata/rules:rw" is used in service "suricata" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

this is my docker-compose.yaml file
version: "2"

services:
  swag:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/swag
    container_name: swag
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - URL=wiki.greatguidemagic.com
      - VALIDATION=https
    volumes:
      - ./data/config_swag:/config
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - lsio  # SWAG communicates on the lsio network

  bookstack:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/bookstack
    container_name: bookstack
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - APP_URL=${URL}
      - DB_HOST=bookstack_db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=bookstack
      - DB_PASS=${DB_PASS}
      - DB_DATABASE=bookstackapp
    volumes:
      - ./data/app_bookstack:/config
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - bookstack_db
    networks:
      - default  # BookStack uses the default network

  bookstack_db:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb
    container_name: bookstack_db
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT}
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstackapp
      - MYSQL_USER=bookstack
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
    volumes:
      - ./data/db_bookstack:/config
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - default  # BookStack database uses the default network

  # Suricata Intrusion Detection System
  suricata:
    image: jasonish/docker-suricata:latest  # Replace with your preferred Suricata image if needed
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
      - SYS_NICE
    volumes:
      - ./suricata.yaml:/etc/suricata/suricata.yaml:ro  # Mount your configuration file (read-only)
      - suricata_rules:/var/lib/suricata/rules:rw  # Define and mount the volume for rules (read-write)
      - suricata_logs:/var/log/suricata
    networks:
      - host  # Suricata monitors the host network

# Assuming "lsio" is an external network managed elsewhere
networks:
  lsio:
    external: true

can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong/help me!?
I tried to restart docker a vew times but nothing seemed to be working

As the error message says: if you have volumes: [suricata_rules: /path] in a container, then you need a top-level volumes: block that declares those volumes.  If you need both host networking and NET_ADMIN capability, you're disabling a significant fraction of Docker's isolation capabilities, and it might be better to run this program outside a container.
